# Log of matrix with unit trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, linear-algebra

If we take the log of a operator/matrix with unit trace what constraints can be imposed on the result?
I need to find a density operator. I have one less than enough constraints to find all the elements of the log of the density operator. Now, taking the condition of unit trace, I have enough constraints. However, how does the constraint affect the log of the density matrix?

Comment: Is your density operator pure? In that case the log is undefined but the Von Neumann entropy is defined to be zero (in some limiting procedure). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Entropy

Comment: No! The density operator is not necessarily pure.

Comment: The trace is invariant under similarity transformation, so the trace is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, right?  Does the fact that your eigenvalues sum to 1 help somehow?